# ggplot2 scatter plot of data in long format with unknown/variable site names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make scatter plot which compares values at different sites which are input in long format.

I can do this easily using fixed site names, but I want to be able to run it with different site names in the input data. Currently the script converts the data to wide format and then plots them, but this means I have to manually change the site names.

Initially I'm happy if it just works when I have 2 sites in the input data, but bonus points if it has 3 sites for making all combination of sites and combining them similar to what I have done below.

Is there any functionality in ggplot to create a scatter from a long dataframe?

I found a similar question [Scatter plot in ggplot, one numeric variable across two groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618041/scatter-plot-in-ggplot-one-numeric-variable-across-two-groups) but its answer was basically my starting point, but it didn't have the problem where the correlation names may change.

The below code gives me what I want, but if I changed the input data (eg changed Site to `rep(letters[4:6],each = 10)` it would become useless.

```r
  library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2)
testdf <- tibble(Site = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10), x = rep(1:10,3), y = rnorm(30, mean = 1, sd = 0.05)*x)


testdf_w <- pivot_wider(testdf, names_from = Site, values_from = y)

p1 <- ggplot(testdf_w, aes(x = a, y = b))+
  geom_point()

p1 # This is all I'd need if there were only 2 sites
```

[image]

```r
library(patchwork)
#> Warning: package 'patchwork' was built under R version 3.5.3

p2 <- ggplot(testdf_w, aes(x = a, y = c))+
  geom_point()

p3 <- ggplot(testdf_w, aes(x = b, y = c))+
  geom_point()

p1 + p2 + p3
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over combinations of unique site names and use `aes_string` to specify column names as string.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2)
testdf <- tibble(Site = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10),
                 x = rep(1:10,3),
                 y = rnorm(30, mean = 1, sd = 0.05)*x)
testdf_w <- pivot_wider(testdf, names_from = Site, values_from = y)


library(patchwork)
sites <- unique(testdf$Site)
p <- NULL
for (s1 in sites) {
  for (s2 in sites) {
    if (s1 >= s2) next

    tmp <- ggplot(testdf_w, aes_string(x = s1, y = s2)) +
      geom_point()
    if (is.null(p)) {
      p <- tmp
    } else {
      p <- p + tmp
    }
  }
}
p
```

[image]

In addition, you may also like `ggpairs` for this particular application.

```r
library(GGally)
ggpairs(select(testdf_w, -x))
```

[image]